# How to retrieve value from SP.Data.UserInfoItem- rest odata

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest

When i retrieve data from a person and group column this is what i get as a string below

```
{"__metadata":{"id":"3d427c6e-2322-4121-b106-f248277eab3f","type":"SP.Data.UserInfoItem"},"LastName":"XXX"}
```

How can i retrieve XXX ad not the whole metadata string

Currently i'm doing the below

```
var myAngApp = angular.module('SharePointAngApp', []);  
    myAngApp.controller('spCustomerController', function ($scope, $http) {  
        $http({  
            method: 'GET',  
            //url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title",  
           url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,Notify/LastName&$expand=Notify/id",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }  
        }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {  
            $scope.customers = data.d.results;  
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {  

        });  
    });
```

Comment: Do you mean you do **not** want to use $expand? If so you have to do multiple queries (which expand does for you server-side)

Comment: Thanks Danny for the response but thats not the case
Will modify my question

Comment: You probably want ``nometadata`` instead of ``verbose``, but you will still get a JSON object, not just XXXX

Answer (score 0):

an API result is always some type of Object, hardly ever a string

Note that the SP Search API returns a completely different JSON structure than calling a List endpoint

So you have to proces the result yourself to get a single value.

You can trim down how much you get back with the `nometadata` , `minimalmetadata` settings:
https://blogs.office.com/2014/08/13/json-light-support-rest-sharepoint-api-released/

JavaScript to learn:

- Object.keys() https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys
- Array methods (*the FOR loop is used by people who do not understand JS, or JS experts*)
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thanks guys for the response. My issue is how can i retrieve a Person or Group field. Using this    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Test')/items?$select=Title,Notify/LastName&$expand=Notify/id",
I can receive the title but i can't get to retrieve a name instead i get an object "{"__metadata":{"id":"3d427c6e-2322-4121-b106-f248277eab3f","type":"SP.Data.UserInfoItem"},"LastName":"XXX"}"

Comment: Got it. Just needed to add this {{customer.Notify.Title}}